# Onesignal push notification as banner(Currently it only provides alert not showing any popup) with version 3.x)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

Currently we are using one signal version 3.3.0

With this our current requirement is to show notification in popup in android and ios.

How can we achieve that?

OneSignal.setAppId(key);

Current Behaviour

It was only provide alert . Not such banner.

There is are solution for this like provide in below link but those are for version 2.x.
OneSignal/react-native-onesignal#918

Actual Result:

Showing notification in popup in ios and android like below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a channel Category as described in the documentation.
  https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-categories
- Set importance as **urgent** for the category.
  (You can set *android_channel_id* in your REST API call to this channel Category ID)
- And boom it works.

You might need to reset your notifications permissions,if doesn't works a first place.